# .htaccess: param url to clean url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to turn an ugly url with parameters into a nice url. At the moment I have:

> http://myasite.com/index.php?reg=uk&area=london&id=16

Which I would like to have like so:

> http://myasite.com/uk/london/16

I have tried using this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$/?$ index.php?reg=$1&area=london&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Which I got from an online generator however when I run the page with /uk/16 in the url it just crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

In reply to Chris's reply below. All of these are optional.

Structure of url is like so:

```
myasite.com
myasite.com/uk (if set, This will always be text and always 2 chars long)
myasite.com/uk/london (if set, This will always be text, this will be any char length )
myasite.com/uk/london/16 (if set, This will always be integer and any char length)
```

Comment: What are acceptable values for `reg` and `id`? Id is probably just an integer? What you are doing wrong is the regex. `/?$/?` says there can be 2 optional `/`s, nothing else.

Comment: @chris85 I made a lil mistake when writing my q - Please see new post

Comment: @chris85 yup I figured as much. but I am honestly a bit over my head with this. Not sure what i'm doing. I need all three to work but also not to crash if one isnt set. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is incorrect. Your `^/?$/?$` says the request can have 2 `/`s only, each is optional. You also aren't using any capture groups so `$1` and `$2` have no context. Here's a regex that would work for your provided example:

```
^/(uk)/(\d+)$
```

If `uk` can be any 2 lowercase letters you could use:

```
^/([a-z]{2})/(\d+)$
```

You can use regex101 to see how your regexs will function.

https://regex101.com/r/VyJE9d/1 (your rule)
https://regex101.com/r/VyJE9d/2

The right side of the page gives explanations.

As a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})/(\d+)$ index.php?reg=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Per your update you will need to have 3 rules. Please use the regex101 link and if you have questions with the regexs ask.

Comment: If I do not set the last two params I get a 404. I tried wrapping each in ()? but that didnt work. Damn I suck at this. https://regex101.com/r/VyJE9d/3

Comment: Oh, I forgot to paren the city/area. "directory" 2 should have had `()` around it. So `RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+?)/(\d+)$ index.php?reg=$1&id=$3&area=$2 [L,QSA]` i think would do it for `http://myasite.com/uk/london/16`.

Comment: I am getting 404 on any stage /uk and /uk/london and uk/london/16. any ideas?

Comment: Do you have base rewrite rule on? Maybe `RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+?)/(\d+)$ index.php?reg=$1&id=$3&area=$2 [L,QSA]`... or make the leading `/` optional..

Comment: nope. This is my entire htaccess file: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+?)/(\d+)$ index.php?reg=$1&n=$3&area=$2 [L,QSA] - tried your new line too and still 404.

Comment: I can't replicate behavior. http://chrisisdoingwhat.com/james/uk/london/16 PHP: `<?php
print_r($_GET);` htaccess: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+?)/(\d+)$ index.php?reg=$1&n=$3&area=$2 [L,QSA]` Note you changed the param name to `n` from `area`, is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to use is this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?reg=$1&area=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

This will leave you with your desired URL of: `http://myasite.com/uk/london/16`. Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?reg=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

We are rewriting `$1/$2/` and `$1/$2` to `index.php?reg=$1&id=$2`

Comment: Whoever did the -1 please comment!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it